# If tuples are described as sequence types, why is a tuple of length 1 treated as a scalar?

Tags: python, list, operators, tuples

I'm just starting to learn Python and was playing around with the `in` operator in the interpreter and discovered something interesting. Why is this `False`:

```
# case 1
>>> [1] in [1,2,3]
False
```

but these are `True`?

```
# case 2
>>> [1] in [[1],2,3]
True

# case 3
>>> (1) in [(1),2,3]
True

# case 4
>>> (1) in [1,2,3]
True

# case 5
>>> 1 in [(1),2,3]
True
```

I can understand why #1 is `False`, since `[1]` is a list object and it does not occur in the list `[1,2,3]`. I also get why #2 is `True`. However, if tuples are immutable lists (as Norm Matloff describes them in his [tutorial](http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/python.html)) or are immutable sequences (as the Python documentation for TUPLES says), why is `(1)` equated to `1` instead of `[1]`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Brackets do not make a tuple, a comma does.

```
>>> (1)
1
>>> (1,)
(1,)
```

So where you do `(1)`, it actually just means `1`.

```
>>> (1,) in [1,2,3]
False
```